# Laying out dates in Google Sheets charts

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a Google Sheets with measurements made at different dates. The data looks like this:

```
2010-09-01 80
2010-09-02 79
2010-09-10 81
```

I want the points that make up the data to be laid out so that the first date is at `x0`, second date at `x0 + 1` and the third date at `x0 + 9`. So far I have only been able to produce graphs where the first date is at `x0`, the second at `x0 + 1` and the third at `x0 + 2`.

How can I make a chart with the dates spread along the x axis properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this is possible to do in a Google spreadsheet now.

If I enter the data from my question, highlight it and select insert chart from the menu, Google Spreadsheet will greate a trend graph with the points laid out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's still not yet possible with Google spreadsheets.

Look at the thread on google's support forum for tips and updates

[Google Forums - date in a chart](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=5cea8659f9b3bd29&hl=en)